# mod_rewrite to redirect to specific WP page

Tags: mod-rewrite

The goal is to redirect all requests coming to Wordpress from IE 6 and 7, to a specific Wordpress page using mod_rewrite.

My confusion comes from multiple conditions that are needed for the rewrite not entering an endless loop once on the specific Wordpress page. So the condition must be: (IE 6 or 7) and request is not the same as the page we are sending them to.

I've tried things along the lines of:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} MSIE\ ([67])\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !iepage
RewriteRule .* /iepage/ [R]
```

In IE 6 and 7, I get page cannot be displayed errors. Could it really mean too many redirects, because the 2nd condition isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking the current URI in the `RewriteRule` instead.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} MSIE\ ([67])\.
RewriteRule !^/iepage/$ /iepage/ [R]
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you not just missing a leading slash

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/iepage$
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. You're right, but the error is still the same in IE 6 and 7.